# database clean up in acceptance tests with specflow

Tags: database, specflow, acceptance-testing

I am a newbie in tdd. I have watched Brandon Satrom's videos. I am trying to implement tests like them ,outer loop for acceptance tests and inner loop for unit tests. I have thought acceptance test was againist to Database ,too.So i expect to find examples about [BeginScenario/AfterScenario] events for database clean up in Specflow.It is said to be used for database Clean up. But None of the examples i saw do it.

Am i misundestanding the acceptance test concept? Doesn't it cover the database too? Should we use mock objects there like we did in unit tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using a real MS SQL Server database in my integration unit tests (MSTest) and acceptance testing with BDD tool SpecFlow in this way: I have a dump of my test database (MDF/LDF files) stored as a template. On test initialize I copy them to a temporary location, attach them to a dedicated SQL Server using sp_attach_db stored procedure (you may use an Express edition for this), then I run whatever test code I want and on test cleanup I detach the test database and delete the MDF/LDF files. The whole copy/attach/detach/delete cycle is pretty fast (at least much faster than I thought before).
If you're interested, I could put it into some more words on my blog.

Comment: it seems to be easier than cleaning created rows. I'd like to try it.I'll be good see some more details on your blog.

Comment: Don't forget that transaction scopes can minimize the cleanup required. But this is still nice for *staging* a database to start with!

Answer (score 2):

At last i am convinced that i must use the real database in my acceptance tests. I have to see some examples, and read it from several resources before i settle it in my mind.

Now i am using acceptence test as supposed for testing the flow of my user interfaces and database.
i wrote a happy path scenerio for my registration page to design page flow. then i wrote some test for logic that kept in my stored procedures in database. Other logic is on controllers and model classes. So for them i used unit tests. Now it makes more sense to me, until my next confusion about tdd :).

As for clean up process, i use  [BeginScenario/AfterScenario]  events. At BeginScenario i use a global varible to keep a DateTime.Now.Ticks value and merge it in beginnigs of the values that i sent to db. Then i find the records that start with this  DateTime.Now.Ticks value when i making the clean up for that scenario at AfterScenario event. So it helped me to make unique values that doesnt interfere with other records. It seemed to work by now.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding this matter, [this](http://graemehill.ca/high-performance-database-rollback-in-automated-tests-with-sql-server) article, is very helpful.

It describes the use of transactions in MSDTC, starting at BeginScenario and rolled back at AfterScenario. 
(SpecFlow is not used in the article, but its the same concept)

We are currently using this technique with success in a mid scale development project.

Comment: I would urge serious caution about utilizing transactions for database cleanup of automated tests for an enterprise solution.  If you have a consistent and well thought out transaction architecture in the code, then you may be able to build your tests around this.  If you try to add in transaction architecture after, you may be in trouble.  E.g., TransactionScope will not upgrade a transaction level, so if you wrapped a test that includes (now nested) transactions at different levels, it will fail.  You're probably better off cleaning up or performing integration tests on a fresh DB.

Comment: Good point!!! Code depending on keeping track on transaction levels etc is probably not at all a good subject for use of the "MSDTC rollback on AfterScenario" technique.